# How does the Snowpipe cloud messaging mechanism exactly work on Azure?

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-eventgrid, azure-queues

I've successfully integrated Snowpipe with a container inside the Azure storage and loaded data into my target table, but now I can't exactly figure out how does Snowpipe actually works. Also, please let me know if there is already a good resource that answers this question, I'd be very grateful.

In my example, I tested a Snowpipe mechanism that uses cloud messaging. So, from my understanding, when a file is uploaded into an Azure container, Azure Event Grid sends an event message to an Azure queue, from which Snowpipe is notified that a new file is uploaded into the container. Then, Snowpipe in the background starts its loading process and imports the data into a target table.

If this is correct, I don't understand how does Azure queue informs Snowpipe about uploaded files. Is this connected to the "notification integration" inside Snowflake? Also, I don't understand what does it mean when they say on the Snowflake [page](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-intro.html#how-does-snowpipe-work) that "Snowpipe copies the files into a queue, from which they are loaded into the target table...". Is this an Azure queue or some Snowflake queue?

I hope this question makes sense, any help or detailed explanation of the whole process is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much nailed it. to answer your specific questions... (and don't feel bad about them, this is definitely confusing)

- how does Azure queue informs Snowpipe about uploaded files? Is this connected to the "notification integration" inside Snowflake?

  - Yes, this is the notification integration. But Azure is not "informing" the Snowpipe, it's the other way around. The Azure queue creates a notification that various other applications can subscribe to (this has no awareness of Snowflake). The notification integration on the snowflake side is snowflake's way to **integrate** with these external **notifications**
- Snowpipe's queueing

  - Once snowflake recieves one of these notifications it puts that notification into a snowflake-side queue (or according to that page, the file itself. I was surprised by this, but the end result is the same). Snowpipes are wired up to that notification integration (as part of the create statement). The files are directed to the appropriate snowpipe based on the information in the "Stage" (also as part of the pipe create statement. I'm actually not certain if this part is a push or a pull). Then it runs the `COPY INTO` on that file.

Comment: Thank you for your response, and for confirming some of my assumptions! It is a little clearer now.